# Problem Solving Strategies (by Arthur Engel): A number theory problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This example problem is from Arthur Engel's PSS, in the chapter about the invariance principle.

Each of the numbers $a_1$ ... $a_n$ is $1$ or $-1$, and we have

$S$ = $a_1$$a_2$$a_3$$a_4$ + $a_2$$a_3$$a_4$$a_5$ + ... + $a_n$$a_1$$a_2$$a_3$ = $0$

Prove that $4$ | $n$.

I think I solved the problem but it looks quite under-developed compared to the solution in the book.

Here's my approach:

Let $1$ $\leqslant$ $i$ $\leqslant$ $n$ ,

I tried to figure out how many "$a_i$s" appear in $S$. If we treat each term like a four-digit number, $a_i$$a_{i+1}$$a_{i+2}$$a_{i+3}$ then the next term is just a digit replacing the digit before, with $a_{i+3}$ replaced by $a_{i+4}$. From this we see that same digits cannot take up a sample "place" of a term more than once. We can also observe that $a_i$ appears four times in $S$.

Now, we can define a sum $S_i$ = $a_1$$a_1$$a_1$$a_1$ + $a_2$$a_2$$a_2$$a_2$ + ... + $a_n$$a_n$$a_n$$a_n$, which is equal to $n$. $n$ is divisible by 4 because each term is expressed as a group of four same digits. Therefore, $4$ | $n$.

I feel that something is missing and I would thank you for some advice.

Comment: [BruceBrain](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/586786/brucebrain) asks: How do you know that $S_i$ is equal to $n$?

Comment: each term in   is 1 in both cases in which  = 1 or -1, because it is multiplied four times. There are total n terms in , so 1 x n = n.